# REGEX doesn't match string if substring has already been matched

Tags: python, regex

[image: As seen here, the keyword Social Media was already matched so Social Media Wall is not being matched, Although it's different with the case of ERP as ERP and ERP Corecon both are matched.]

Input Text  -

```
hey, G Suite , ,Social Media Wall, Social Media Wall , ERP ERP Corecon
```

Query -

```
((?<=[,-./\s])(ERP Corecon|Social Media|Social Media Wall|ROI|ERP)\b)
```

Output -

```
hey, G Suite , ,**Social Media** Wall, **Social Media** Wall , **ERP** **ERP Corecon**
```

Ideal Output -
Social Media & Social Media Wall both should be matched

regex link - https://regexr.com/6ugr5

Comment: Put the longer match before the shorter one in the query, like you did with ERP Corecon and ERP?

Comment: https://regexr.com/6ugr5 @anubhava

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson yes that can be done, but my regex pattern is auto-generated and I don't have control over that. Instead, I would prefer a regex pattern that can accommodate this. Also, I am trying to understand the reason why is Social Media Wall not  being matched

Comment: When there are multiple matching alternatives, the result depends on the regexp engine. Some always prefer the longer match, some prefer the first match in the alternatives. I don't think there's a way to force one to act like the other.

Comment: @anubhava added input text to question - 
hey, G Suite , ,Social Media Wall, Social Media Wall , ERP ERP Corecon

Comment: You can use: `(?<=[,-./\s])(ERP(?: Corecon)?|Social Media(?: Wall)?|ROI)\b`

Comment: What's funny is that in your char-class there is a range `,-.` which is probably not meant like this by intention, but it matches ascii 44-46 and the index 45 is a minus.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use this regex:

```bash
(?<=[,-./\s])(ERP(?: Corecon)?|Social Media(?: Wall)?|ROI)\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sbsh54/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `(?<=[,-./\s])`: Lookbehind to assert presence of these chars before current position
- `(`; Start capture group

  - `ERP(?: Corecon)?`: Match `ERP` or `ERP Corecon`
  - `|`: OR
  - `Social Media(?: Wall)?`: Match `Social Media` or `Social Media Wall`
  - `|`: OR
  - `ROI`: Match `ROI`
- `)`: End capture group
- `\b`: Word boundary

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use named groups:

```
(?<SocialMediaWall>(?<SocialMedia>Social Media)( Wall)?)|(?<ERPCore>(?<ERP>ERP)( Corecon)?)|(?<ROI>ROI)
```

As you can see, the `SocialMedia` group is nested inside the `SocialMediaWall` group. That's a way of getting both values.

Answer (score 0):

All your solutions were intriguing but I end up sorting my regex query into descending where the longer keywords came first, thus never allowing a substring to come before a string. This solved my problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).